# Wilcard certificate with alt names

Tags: ssl, certificate, wildcard

I would like to have a Wild card SSL Certificate with alternative names. I have asked the question to SSL Certificate providers and they answer that I should use a UCC certificate however the UCC did not allow me to setup multiple websites in the same IIS.

Answer (score 0):

WildCard SSL Certificate can protect only single level domains such as *.domain.com, edit.domain.com. So make sure that you are trying to protect single level domains with UCC SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

UCC certificate will allow you setup multiple website in the same IIS server. It'll allow you to reduce your cost. And more beneficial thing is, it'll free you from harassing process of multiple certificate management.